# RewriteRule forbidden for empty Request URI

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write `.htaccess` rules to deny access to all [`.php`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) files in all subfolders but allow access to one single file in one of subdirectories and also using a [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) on that file, it works if `Request URI` is not empty but when I access `/` it shows **Forbidden**

Now I have :

```
<Files ~ "\.(php)$">
   deny from all
</Files>

<Files Test.php>
   allow from all
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /Sub/Test.php [QSA]
```

**How to make it to work as expected?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you request `/`, it gets mapped to `index.php` or whatever your index file is and this condition then fails:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

You could add an additional *or*'ed condition to also allow the `/` request through:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /Sub/Test.php [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually all this blocking of `.php` can be easily handled in just 2 rules. Consider this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# block any request with `.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# send all non-file, non-dir requests to /Sub/Test.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.+$ /Sub/Test.php [L]
```